# Fitting complex non-linear function with nls() in R gives singular gradient error

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, nls

I am trying to fit oral pharmacokinetic function using R nls. The function can be seen here:
[image]

I tried the following:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
        Time = c(10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 60, 90, 120, 180, 210, 240, 300, 360),
        C_PO = c(0,0.28,0.55,1.2,2,1.95,1.85,1.6,
                 0.86,0.78,0.6,0.21,0.18))

plot(dat$C_PO ~ dat$Time, data = dat, log = "y")

fit <- nls(C_PO~ka*100* (exp(-k*Time) - exp(-ka*Time))/(v*(ka- k)),
    data = dat,
    start = list(ka = 0.09, k = 0.01, v = 50))
#> Error in nls(C_PO ~ ka * 100 * (exp(-k * Time) - exp(-ka * Time))/(v * : singular gradient
```

The code is trying to fit a non-linear model according to the concentration values `C_PO` over a time period `Time`. The initial values were calculated using graph stripping methods. However, the error message reads "singular gradient." How can this be fixed?

Comment: You can use `minpack.lm` or `gslnls` for better non-linear model fitting.

Comment: As it is, one issue is that division by zero is possible. As a first step, you should substitute `deltak = ka - k` and `ka = deltak + k`. Then you should set lower boundaries for the parameters (and `algorithm = "port"` if you use `nls`). However, I was not able to get a successful fit where `deltak` was not at the lower boundary. Even if you get a successfull fit with one of the optimizers suggested by comments and answers, you should be wary. Better repeat the experiment a few times to get more (reliable) data.

Comment: Are you sure you have the equation right? Often difficulty in fitting suggests that the wrong model is being used. Usually here one uses the biexponential function.  See `?SSbiexp`  and in PK package see `?biexp` .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I find these self starting functions interesting. But In this case, the equation I have should be able to descibe it. My question is if those functions can give also the formula?

Comment: @UseR10085 Can you elaborate  briefly how do they differ?

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to avoid zeros by adding constraints from not on.

Comment: @PPenton, The biexponential does fit your data better than the model in the question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck The thing is that in PK I don't always easily understanding the data relationships.  So, these derived forms are very helpful.

Comment: The problem is that what you believe is the model isn't really how it works.  Good models don't depend on the 7th decimal and they fit easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gslnls` package for fitting non-linear model like

```
library(gslnls)

dat <- data.frame(
  Time = c(10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 60, 90, 120, 180, 210, 240, 300, 360),
  C_PO = c(0,0.28,0.55,1.2,2,1.95,1.85,1.6,
           0.86,0.78,0.6,0.21,0.18))

plot(dat$C_PO ~ dat$Time, data = dat, log = "y")

fit <- gsl_nls(C_PO ~ ka*100* (exp(-k*Time) - exp(-ka*Time))/(v*(ka- k)), 
                    data = dat, 
                    start = c(ka = 0.09, k = 0.01, v = 50), 
                    control = gsl_nls_control(maxiter = 500))

summary(fit)

#> Formula: C_PO ~ ka * 100 * (exp(-k * Time) - exp(-ka * Time))/(v * (ka - 
#>     k))
#> 
#> Parameters:
#>     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> ka    0.0132     4.0027   0.003    0.997
#> k     0.0132     4.0025   0.003    0.997
#> v    21.0181  6372.7704   0.003    0.997
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.3363 on 10 degrees of freedom
#> 
#> Number of iterations to convergence: 18 
#> Achieved convergence tolerance: 0
```

Comment: Well, the most important information you get from this fit are the standard errors (and `vcov(fit)`).

Comment: @UseR10085 That works! Thank you. But these parameters should be restrained to above zero. Is there is any way to do that?

Comment: The fact that k and ka are the same to 6 decimals seems suspicious.